# NoClassDefFoundError when running plugin in new Eclipse application

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins, eclipse-pde

I am trying to solve this for about a week now so I'll be very grateful for any help.
I am developing an Eclipse plugin. I need to read the pom.xml file in my code. To do this I need three maven dependencies.
The project was created as plugin project and then converted to Maven project using m2eclipse. This is my POM:

```
<properties>
<tycho-version>0.25.0</tycho-version>

<manifest-location>META-INF</manifest-location>

<name>${project.name}</name>
<version>${project.version}</version>
</properties>

<repositories>
  <repository>
      <id>eclipse-mars</id>
      <layout>p2</layout>
      <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.22</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.9</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Now when I run new Eclipse app to test the plugin. It throws an exception: ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/model/io/xpp3/MavenXpp3Reader

Same goes with Apache HttpClient as a Maven dependency. For this I was able to solve it by importing bunch of org.apache.http packages.
I also tried [this](https://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.git/tree/tycho-its/projects/TYCHO309pomDependencyConsider/pom.xml) which didnt help. 
This really bugs me because in all the articles and tutorials is written it should work.(that m2eclipse manages maven dependencies automatically).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Maven, but as an Eclipse plug-in (osgi bundle) in order to access the class at run-time you will need to add a dependency to the package or bundle that provides those classes.

This is done in the plugin/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file with an `Import-Package` or `Require-Bundle` manifest header.  I don't know if maven/tycho does this automatically for you or not.

Also, the plug-in/bundle that provides those classes needs to specify an `Export-Package` in their manifest.